# Playonlinux error - an error occured during the download

Tags: playonlinux, photoshop

I'm trying to install photoshop on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm getting the following error during the installation:

[image]

I guess the problem is because the link: http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/svpk/2008/04/windowsxp-kb936929-sp3-x86-enu_c81472f7eeea2eca421e1 isn't vaild anymore.
How can i solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the issue by downloading the file from microsoft.com and placing it into ~/.PlayOnLinux/ressources/ folder

```
wget http://xpsp.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/d/3/0/d30e32d8-418a-469d-b600-f32ce3edf42d/WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe
mv WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe ~/.PlayOnLinux/ressources/
```

Note: The folder is named ressources with two "S", it is not a typo error.

Comment: worked like a charm